# How to remove an entry from a list with a discord bot

Tags: indexing, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl, playlist

I have a music bot that has support for playlist. For that I made a `playlist` command which displays the queue. I also have a command that clears the full queue. Now I would like to implement the possibility to remove a single song by number from a list. How would I have to re-write the following command?

```py
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.guild)
    @commands.command(aliases=["delplaylist"])
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.check(audio_playing)
    async def remove(self, ctx):
        """Deletes a single song from the playlist."""
        state = self.get_state(ctx.guild)
        entries = []
        for (index, song) in enumerate(state.playlist):
            entries.append(
                (f"**[{index + 1}]  {song.title}** *by* {song.uploader}", f"requested by {song.requested_by.mention}"))
        pages = PlaylistPages(ctx, entries)
        return await pages.paginate()
```

I know for fact that the code just shows the playlist itself. I would start by getting the `entries` and remove them by number, but is that possible in that "easy" way?

Comment: "by number" you mean by index, right?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Yes, sorry. I want to remove an index from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove by index:

Using the [`del` keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp)

```py
>>> lst = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
>>> del lst[0] # The index of the element
>>> lst
['elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
```

Using [`list.pop`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop)

```py
>>> lst = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
>>> lst.pop(0) # It also returns the value
'elem1'
>>> lst
['elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
```

Comment: How would I implement this into a command for a user? I would take the index of the song: `song = state.playlist.pop(song - 1)` and then remove it by? `state.playlist.remove[...]`

Comment: list.pop will already remove it from the list

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it pops the song out of the list. However if I want to remove index 7 from a list with `remove 7` it just pops the first song. Do you have a clue on how to change this?

Comment: `list.pop(index)` takes an integer (the index of the element which to remove), if you want to delete by an element, use `list.remove(elem)`. Sorry if the answer confused you.

Comment: That helped, thanks. I used `song = state.playlist.pop(song - 1)`.